# Horizontal Scrolling with Mousewheel

Tags: jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'm using Chris Coyier's method of encapsulating table cells around divs via js to achieve horizontal scrolling  http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-a-horizontally-scrolling-site/ . However, to scroll you had to either have a mouse with horizontal scrolling or hold shift while scrolling.

So, I used this hscroll.js plugin http://paulicio.us/items/view/24/horizontal-page-scrolling-using-javascript which lets you scroll the page laterally via mousewheel.

But there is a considerable lag/choppiness when tested in Firefox and Opera(works fine in Chrome and Safari). I think Brandon Aaron's mousewheel.js http://brandonaaron.net/code/mousewheel/docs would be the viable solution but I don't know how to implement the plugin as I'm illiterate when it comes to js.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/694TK/3/

**Update:** The tinyscroll plugin seems to work fine except it doesn't have easing, any solution for that?: http://jsfiddle.net/694TK/6/

**Yet another Update:** http://jsbin.com/uwehot/

Mary Lou's circular content carousel*(http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/16/circular-content-carousel/)* at play here. 
It works quite well, except that anchor links won't work.

Comment: May I ask you wan't to make a dynamic site or some static one?

Comment: Dynamic. That's why I went with the table method. Otherwise I'd have to define the width of the body with an ungodly measurement.

Comment: I'm not inclined to use html5 right now. But as far as I know you have to define the body's width when using divs.

Comment: Take also a look over here. http://bit.ly/yaV2BQ

Comment: It doesn't have mousewheel support man. Thanks for the effort though. :]

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I don't think so that the table approach is good enough.
Try to wrap your paragraphs and set anchor Links to the titles

That anchor links will be the start-stop "marks" for your animation.
Each time a user starts to scroll (the event will be triggered by your plugin) the animation starts and ends to the next anchor
Look an [example](http://www.arvindandrion.com/jquery/horizontal-scroll-using-jquery-scrollto/)

This guy uses the button click events to trigger his animation

```
$('#btn_two').click(function(){
$('.nav').fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("slow");
$.scrollTo(this.hash, 1500, { easing:'elasout' });
});
```

You will use mousewheel event.
That's a little violent approach though
In order to move smoothly as the user scrolls is to use the easing plugin

Comment: Can you jsfiddle an example?
Anyways, I came across this old plugin: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32750720/res/thw.js It doesn't have easing and I haven't tested the page with the rest of the css flair added, but it seems to work quite alright: http://jsfiddle.net/694TK/6/